# Too many supported localizations in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

When I uploaded an update to an app to Google Play today it showed that we suddenly support 63 new languages, which we don't. Any idea what is causing this?

[image: Google Play Screenshot]

Comment: The problem is in the apk you uploaded, not with google play. Replace .apk with zip, unzip it, and look at the res/ folder. You'll see that gradle automatically generated lots of folders for each of those additional 63 languages. Here is the solution: http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have added a new library, such as Google Play Services, to your package which is adding its own resource files for additional languages.

If you are using Android Studio, you can set `resConfigs` to disable unsupported locales. See *[Putting Your APKs on Diet](http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/) -> Minimize resources configurations* by Cyril Mottier:

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    resConfigs "en", "de", "fr", "it"
}
```